# How can I use groups with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have some data that will be one of the following

```
Word Number Word Number  
Word Number Word Word Number  
Word Word Number Word Number  
Word Word Number Word Word Number
```

I would like to extract the Word(s) up until the numbers, and the numbers. Here is what I have at the moment (which looks OK to me, but I don't fully understand regex).

```
    preg_match('/([A-Za-z ])([0-9])([A-Za-z ])([0-9])/', $game, $info);
    print_r($info);
```

However, the array is empty. I know I've seen `^` and `+` and `$` used before but I'm not quite sure how to work it into the regex.

Comment: Do you mean `Number` is a *digit*?

Comment: Try `preg_match_all('/([A-Za-z ]+)([0-9]+)([A-Za-z ]+)([0-9]+)/', $game, $info);` or `preg_match_all('/^([A-Za-z ]+)([0-9]+)([A-Za-z ]+)([0-9]+)$/', $game, $info);`.

Comment: @Shafizadeh yes sorry. Word as in a string of letters (with possible space in between) then a space, then a digit, then a space, then a string of letters (with possible space) then a digit again.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's perfect, thank you. Just one question, is $info[0] supposed to be the original string (all groups together)?

Comment: @cantsay: That regex is not perfect, it can be improved. `$info[0]` contains the whole match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just replaced `A-Za-z` with `a-z` and used `/i`. any other suggestions? (I'm happy to Google if you let me know the keywords) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match the strings with the format you described, you need

```
preg_match_all('/^([a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)?)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)?)\s+([0-9]+)$/im', $game, $info);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE9dH3/1)

[IDEONE demo:](http://ideone.com/5dGAgb)

```
$re = '~^([a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)?)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)?)\s+([0-9]+)$~im'; 
$game = "Word 123 Word 456\nWord 1234 Word Word 3456\nWord Word 3455 Word 4566\nWord Word 4434 Word Word 44332"; 
preg_match_all($re, $game, $info);
print_r($info);
```

The regex explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `([a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)?)` - Group 1 for `Word Word` or `Word` pattern
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 2 for `Number`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `([a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)?)` - Group 3 for `Word Word` or `Word` pattern
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 4 for `Number` pattern
- `$` - end of string

The `/i` modifier makes the pattern case-insensitive. `/m` modifier is used for testing only (it makes `^` and `$` match start and end of a *line*, not the whole string).

The `[a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)?` subpattern means *match one or more letters with `[a-z]+` and then match one or zero occurrence of a sequence of one or more whitespaces (`\s+`) followed with one or more letters (`[a-z]+`). Thus, *this pattern effectively matches 1 or 2 words separated with a whitespace*.

Comment: looks complicated, but it works perfectly. I'll study the explanation on regextester. thank you.

Comment: I added all pertinent details to the answer.